# Когда имеет смысл наследоваться от Thread в Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность, наследование

Читая статью о многопоточности в Java, я наткнулся на следующие строки:

> Считается, что наследование класса Thread следует применять только
>   тогда, когда действительно необходимо создать «новый вид потока,
>   который должен дополнить функциональность класса java.lang.Thread», и
>   подобное решение применяется при разработке системного ПО, например,
>   серверов приложений или инфраструктур.

В каких случаях может понадобиться дополнять функциональность класса Thread? Хотелось бы увидеть практический пример.

Comment: у вас в вопросе содержится ответ. примером может служить сервер приложений Tomcat. в большинстве случаев наследоваться не нужно.

Comment: Единственный случай, когда я вижу рациональность переопределения треда - это вывод дополнительной информации о том, что тред процессит, но в этом случае, как правило, достаточно грамотной смены имени треда (e.g. `scanner:worker-0 [idle]` -> `scanner:worker-0 [webhook execution]` -> `scanner:worker-0 [idle]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JavaFx обновление компонентов интерфейса происходит в JavaFx потоке, т.е. в любой момент можно проверить, выполняется ли данный код в JavaFx потоке или нет. Не берусь утверждать, что этот механизм реализован именно через наследование потоков, но его можно было бы реализовать именно так. В случае JavaFx таким образом заранее запрещается разработчикам делать что либо вне JavaFx потока, чтобы предотвратить асинхронное изменение компонентов интерфейса.

Использование собственных потоков хорошо годится для тех случаев, когда вы хотите запретить выполнение определенных задач в каких-то сторонних потоках, при этом наложив на свои потоки дополнительные ограничения и функционал.

Наследовать Thread может быть полезным тогда, когда вы хотите вести учет своих потоков, вы можете создать новый класс потока, который будет регистрировать новые потоки еще на этапе конструктора. Или если вам требуется особый вид синхронизации, при котором потоки не будут запускаться по какому-нибудь событию, например ограничение по числу параллельно работающих потоков.

С другой стороны практически все связанные с потоками задачи можно реализовать не наследуя, а используя существующие инструменты пакета java.util.concurrent. Многопоточное программирование – достаточно сложная задача, потому лучше использовать готовые компоненты и решения не прибегая к написанию собственных.